# $.ajax POST not working but GET works fine

Tags: php, ajax, post

Been on this for a while now. The codes below works perfectly when " type: 'POST' " is changed to " type: 'GET' ". Any help why its not working for POST?

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://www.example.com/ajax/test.php',
        data: { name: "Overcomer", email : "info@overcomer.we"},
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function() { console.log('firing ajax'); },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText+" - "+thrownError);
        }
    });
```

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**? on the server side? You'd have to show the php handling the request.

Comment: Probably because `test.php` is looking for the parameters in `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: cache will work for GET type. and also as "Barmar" mentioned above use correct global variables based on the Ajax type parameter. For type:post use $_POST and for get use $_GET

Answer (score 1):

Whe you change GET to POST on jquery, you also must change GET to POST in php.

So, on your php code change: `$_GET['name']` to `$_POST['name']` and `$_GET['email']` to `$_POST['email']` as well as any (related) `$_GET` to `$_POST`

If this is not working, post your php code here.

Comment: You can also use `$_REQUEST` in PHP, then it will work with either.

Comment: `$_REQUEST`, by default, contains the contents of `$_GET, $_POST and also $_COOKIE`. There's not much difference about using both, but I like to explicitly choose the method. If you use `$_REQUEST` for everything you have no guarantee that the data came from the post data, which leads to security holes in your script.

Comment: I don't see it as a security hole, since the client can just as easily manipulate the `POST` parameters as cookies.

Comment: True, but there's also `http://php.net/request-order` and `http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order` which depending on the server configuration, might not be working as intended. So to be 100% compatible, you should specify GET or POST.

Comment: When u know u r getting data in post or get than no need to use request..